# Dataverse for Teams(Teams Development)

Tags: microsoft-teams, dataverse

So I know there is a dataverse for teams that is automatically created when you create an app in teams through **power apps**. But Im creating an app through **app studio**(also with visual studio with ms teams extension) and my app needs a database(cds) for saving the records. I *tried to research about it* I dont see any documentation. *Does anyone know how can I use database in teams development?* Or does any one know a documentation about it? I will really appreciate it. Thank youu.

Comment: Hi @user11781598, The Dataverse for Teams environment is used to store, manage, and share team-specific data, apps, and flows. Each team can have one environment, and all data, apps, bots, and flows created with the Power Apps app inside a team are available from that team's Dataverse for Teams database. For more information please check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-teams-environment) document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Teams, you are doing Web development and you can query any database that exposes a Web API. **Dataverse** should work, while **Dataverse for Teams** won't as currently it doesn't offer an API.

If you really need to store the data along with Teams, you could consider SharePoint libraries (for files) and Microsoft Lists (for list items).